# Better <h:selectManyCheckbox> layout?

Tags: java, jsf, facelets

I have a JSF page. At one point, I have a `<h:selectManyCheckbox>` that is displaying a number of items.  The tag provides 2 attributes you can set to define whether the contents should be displayed horizontally or vertically.  However, with more than a few items both choices look bad.  Go with horizontal, and everything ends up bunched up.  Go with vertical, and you can make your page unnecessarily long.  Is there any way to get the best of both worlds?  Specify that there should be x number of columns, for example?  Say I have 20 items and I'd like 4 columns.  If that number grew to 100, I'd still want only 4 columns.  The list would then grow vertically.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Tomahawk's](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/) [`t:selectManyCheckbox`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk/tlddoc/t/selectManyCheckbox.html) instead. It has a `layoutWidth` attribute exactly for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such tag rich:selectManyCheckbox only h:selectManyCheckbox